# Nginx - configure location regex for all static file in sub alias

Tags: file, static, nginx, alias, directive

I've been trying almost one day with no luck to configure nginx as proxy reverse for apache.
I expect that nginx will serve all static file, and the rest is passed to apache.

It's not hard to achieve this if the site resides on the root domain name.

For example, I've successfully set:

```
www.mydomain.com

location ~* \.(jpg|jpeg|gif|png|css|js|ico|xml|rss|txt)$ {
     root /path/to/mysite;
}

location / {
     proxy_pass 127.0.0.1:8080;
     proxy_set_header Host $host;
     proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
     proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
}
```

---

now the problem arises as I want to configure site within alias
for example:
www.mydomain.com/site1

Does anybody know how to achieve the same purpose?

I tried below configuration doesn't work:

```
location /site1 {
    location ~* \.(jpg|jpeg|gif|png|css|js|ico|xml|rss|txt)$ {
            root /path/to/anothersite1;
    }
     proxy_pass apache:8080;
     proxy_set_header Host $host;
     proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
     proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
}
```

the problem is that the 'root' directive doesn't replace the /site1 URI.
For example, a request to

```
www.mydomain.com/site1/folder/pic.jpg
```

will be handled by opening file:

```
/path/to/anothersite1/site1/folder/pic.jpg;
```

instead of:

```
/path/to/anothersite1/folder/pic.jpg
```

I really appreciate any help on this.
I've tried to replace 'root' directive with 'alias' but still no luck.

Thanks beforehand,